# File-transfer download file issue on Cordova 3.1

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer

I'm creating my first webapplication using cordova 3.1.

In this app I need to be able to download a file to the phone and then open it, but i cant seem to get pass how to download the file.

I'm using the file-transfer code from cordovas doc page. Everyting is installed with CLI.

This is how far I've come:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   download();
}    

function download(){
        var filePath = '/mnt/sdcard';
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("https://www.dropbox.com/s/27bxw65u4ga5is0/test.pdf");

        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            filePath,
            function(entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
            },
            false,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                }
            }
        );
}
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<feature name="File">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
</feature>
```

and my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The errors Im getting

```
 E/FileTransfer(878):     {"target":"\/sdcard\/test.pdf","source":"https:\/\/www.dropbox.com\/s\/27bxw65u4ga5is0\/tes t.pdf","http_status":0,"code":1}
 E/FileTransfer(878): java.io.FileNotFoundException:/sdcard/test.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 E/FileTransfer(878):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)         E/FileTransfer(878):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
 E/FileTransfer(878):   at    org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:290)
 E/FileTransfer(878):   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:271)
 E/FileTransfer(878):   at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$4.run(FileTransfer.java:711)
```

I've spent almost 2 days now trying to solve this issue without success.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about 3.1, but for the latest version of Cordova (3.3+), the newer (1.0.0+) version of File uses filesystem URLs instead of the file path. Something like this:

```
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file
```

See the notes at the bottom of this doc: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/31ac00d3ae35f9ca280cf4e6c9edc9df23ea95b5/doc/index.md

Answer (score 4):

cordova 3.3.0
cordova-plugin-file-transfer r 0.4.2
cordova-plugin-file r 1.0.1

TESTED on real devices, works both for Android and iOS

my code:

```
fileTransfer.download(
    "http://my.domain.com/data/sashaTest.txt",
    fileSystem.root.toURL() + "sashaTest.txt", // the key factor !!!
    function(theFile) {
    alert("download complete: " + theFile.toURL());
    console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
    console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
    },
    true
);
```

the target set to: fileSystem.root.toURL() + "sashaTest.txt",

made the difference.

Answer (score 3):

yup, fileSystem.root.**toURL()** is the new player out there and lets you use the latest cdvfile:// url system of Cordova.

Too bad they didn't shared a general notice on this right away. It showed up in [a resolved issue's comments](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5403) and later was documented on the documentation in their GIT repo [as dsims mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21866350).

Once the toURL() thing is clear the download samples as Phonegap/Cordova docs state make sense and will work out.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Internet Permission also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the internet permission snippet is already in the manifest, just forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This was originally edited into the question by the OP. I've moved it to an answer, to be in line with site guidelines.

---

Removed Cordova 3.1 and installed 2.7.0 manually and got it to work.