# Cordova/PhoneGap Open Downloaded File (InAppBrowser)

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

Using Cordova/PhoneGap 3.3.0, I am downloading a file using the FileTransfer plugin, and then trying to open it using the InAppBrowser plugin.  **I can download the file successfully**, and place it in the temp directory.  Since the File plugin now uses URL schema, I cannot figure out how to pass the correct url/path to the `window.open` method of the InAppBrowser plugin.  I cannot find any relevant documentation either.  All of the "download and open" documentation I can find is out of date and pre-URL-schema.

**Relevant links:**

- [Cordova Release info on New Plugin Versions](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/02/10/plugins-release.html)
- [The readme for the FileTransfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md#download)
- [The readme for the InAppBrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md)
- [How to open local file with InAppBrowser with recent changes to URL scheme in File plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831443/how-to-open-local-file-with-inappbrowser-with-recent-changes-to-url-scheme-in-fi#comment33197604_21831443) - Similar question

**Out of date examples I found:**

- [File-transfer download file issue on Cordova 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978369/file-transfer-download-file-issue-on-cordova-3-1) - This user downgraded to an earlier version because they couldn't figure it out
- https://gist.github.com/devgeeks/4982983 - This example uses `entry.fullPath`, which is now deprecated in favor of `toURL()`

Here is my code:

```
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.url/file.pdf");
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0,
    function (fileSystem) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var filename = fileSystem.root.toURL() + uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        fileTransfer.download(uri, filename,
            function(entry) { // download success
                var path = entry.toURL(); //**THIS IS WHAT I NEED**
                window.open(path, "_system");
            },
            function(error) {} // irrelevant download error
        );
    },
    function(error) {} // irrelevant request fileSystem error
);
```

I am currently testing in Android on a Nexus 7 and Nexus 5.  The InAppBrowser correctly opens the default pdf launcher (in my case Adobe Reader), but then I get a "The document path is not valid" error.

**[Update: showing return values]**

I have tried all of the following combinations for the file path:

```
var path = entry.toURL(); // "cdvfile://localhost/temporary/file.pdf"
var path = entry.fullPath; // "file.pdf"
var path = fileSystem.root.toURL() + filename; // "cdvfile://localhost/temporary/file.pdf"
var path = fileSystem.root.fullPath + filename; // "/file.pdf"
```

Comment: if you updated the plugins recently, maybe you have to deal with new URL scheme `cdvfile://`? http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/02/10/plugins-release.html

Comment: Thanks for comment.  I am using these latest plugins, referenced in your provided link.  I read this, but couldn't remember the URL for my posting.  I added it to the relevant links section.  When I call `entry.toURL()` I am getting links with the `cdvfile://` prefix

Comment: stupid question: why don't you use the original url directly with window.open instead of first downloading it?

Comment: It's not a stupid question.  I was doing that previously, but some Android devices display "Cannot open file." error.  It is the oddest thing.  Using that method, the file downloads correctly, and I can open in Adobe through a file explorer, but when opening through Downloads app, the error is displayed.  I thought this was a MIME type issue, but I confirmed that the correct MIME type was being used.  Besides, opening it through the app saves the user an extra step of having to click the downloaded file to open it (assuming it worked correctly anyways).

Comment: maybe try to use the webintent plugin instead of inappbrowser to open the pdf : https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent

Comment: Just installed and used the plugin, and it worked! I had to use the absolute path, but as long as it works I am happy.  If you re-post as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.  Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I THINK I have a solution to this, but it's kinda nasty.

I grepped through the cordova JAVA and looked for places it constructed a file entry JSON object.  Specifically by looking for places where its adding `fullPath` to the object.

I added an additional entry for "fullAbsolutePath" with the value `[file].getAbsolutePath()`, where `[file]` is whatever java.io.file instance is nearby.  I did this in all the places I could find just to be safe and because it doesn't seem to hurt anything.

Then I modified FileEntry.js and File.js in the plugins\file folder to also populate that value to the file entry object.

Still trying to work out the kinks, but I believe I'm on the right track...

I think a better solution would be to modify the inAppBrowser plugin to recognize and resolve the cordovaFile:// protocol and im sure they obscured the absolute file system path on purpose - but that might be a bit beyond me.

EDIT - Yup!  this works!  I can now take a file entry, call the file method, then read fullSystemPath off the fileObject.  Value is like "/storage/emulated/0/whatever/" on my android.  Just need to prepend "file://" and window.open will accept it.

Comment: Thanks for all that work.  I looked at the cordova.java as well to see where you might have put all those references to `fullAbsolutePath`. You might want to submit that to the cordova team for the fileentry or inappbrowser plugins. Can't believe they didn't include that in the updated releases.  I agree though, that it might make more sense to edit inappbrowser to recognize the url correctly.  Glad you got it to work though!

Comment: heh no worries.  I was actually trying to solve the same problem for myself, and figured i'd share.

Comment: @nihlton how would you get a file to save to your app folder?

Answer (score 6):

Since Cordova 3.4 the file protocol has changed and instead of using fullPath they now provide the toURL() that returns a cdvfile://path/to/your/file.ext path.

So when you download a file using the filesystem object's callback (with the entry argument) just call the entry.toURL() and open this using the following statement to open it - assuming you have InApBrowser installed and the _blank will open the InAppBrowser's window:

```
window.open(entry.toURL(), '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close,enableViewportScale=yes');
```

I wrote about it in [this post](http://me.eekay.nl/index.php/2014/how-to-properly-download-and-show-a-frickin-pdf-in-cordova-cli/) on my blog (if you want all the references and background info).

Answer (score 2):

In [the latest cordova docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/dev/doc/index.md) they say

> If you are upgrading to a new (1.0.0 or newer) version of File, and
>   you have previously been using entry.fullPath as arguments to
>   download() or upload(), then you will need to change your code to use
>   filesystem URLs instead.
>
> FileEntry.toURL() and DirectoryEntry.toURL() return a filesystem URL
>   of the form
>
> cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file which can be used in place
>   of the absolute file path in both download() and upload() methods.

What you can try is remove `cdvfile://localhost/persistent` to have a url that would work with your window.open. (maybe start with a alert or console.log of what you get with `entry.toURL()`)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I found this documentation as well, but lost the URL for it.  I have tried using `toURL()`, which also does not return a url that works. I just edited my posting above to show return values. Removing "cdvfile://localhost/temporary" gives me the same result as `entry.fullPath` which also doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe try with 'file:///sdcard/'+entry.fullPath;

Comment: I tried using the absolute path as well, but was unsuccessful with inappbrowser.  However, using the plugin in your previous suggestion I had success!

Answer (score 1):

In current plugin dev branch there is a solution:

**Entry.toNativeURL()** - Returns the full path to the file in the device FileSystem.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/tree/dev

Answer (score 1):

Just write the window.open within the download method or ask for file system and entry again before opening if you want to make it separately

```
function downloadFile(fileURL, destination, fileName) {
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(destination, {
        create: true
    }, function (dirEntry) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.download(fileURL, dirEntry.toURL() + "/fileName", function (entry) {
            alert(fileName + " downloaded successfully at:" + dirEntry.fullPath);
            window.open(dirEntry.toURL() + "fileName", "_blank", "location=yes");
        }, function (error) {
            alert("download failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }, function (error) {
        alert("dir creation failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}, function (error) {
    alert("requesting file system failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

}

if your destination is more than one folder level then you have to ask for getDirectory recursively one by one (if your folders are already created then one call of the method is enough)

PS: - on iOS files are downloaded to 'Documents' folder and not to 'www' so not the same location of your app.js content as some people say
    - if you are opening a html page with js and css from a downloaded unzipped folder then you have to make some changes on InAppBrowser.m to make it load properly

Answer (score 1):

I know this is answered already, but I had the most success with `entry.toInternalURL()`.

Answer (score 0):

The path that follow to "cdvfile://localhost/persistent" is like a root app (www folder) path. In other words, I mean you have access to the images or downloaded files using the path that follow "cdvfile://localhost/persistent".

Example

Download target Path: "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/MyImages/thebestimageever.jpg"

In a HTML image tag I could do this:  `<img src="/MyImages/thebestimageever.jpg" />`

And it works well.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work for mp3 and mp4 files. Only images.